# Model update not triggering consistently

Tags: angularjs

I'm experiencing some very peculiar behaviour--I'm new to angular, to spare you the noob questions, I tired my best to find the solution but after many hours, I think it's time to give in and ask.

**Code Summary**: Alphabet array, is looped(ng-repeat) and each letter is linked to a function called `clickLetter()`, this function sets a $scope variable that reflects the current chosen alphabet letter.

**Problem**: the model/variable in charge of displaying the current active letter is not updating ALL the time, it only appears to update sometimes, randomly it seems.

[Code (plunker)](http://plnkr.co/edit/wRB0ULzq5O8OilJghvkV?p=preview)

My guess is, angular is not updating the model (two-way data-binding?) as fast as it should?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the `<a>` tag is triggering a route change. Either add an `$event.preventDefault()` to it or remove the `<a>` altogether. (doesn't seem like it's adding any value)...

```
<div class="ui icon button padding5" ng-class="{'active': letter == activeLetter}" ng-repeat="letter in letters" ng-click="clickLetter(letter, $event)">
    <a href="#" ng-click="$event.preventDefault()">{{letter}}</a>
</div>
```

or

```
<div class="ui icon button padding5" ng-class="{'active': letter == activeLetter}" ng-repeat="letter in letters" ng-click="clickLetter(letter, $event)">
    {{letter}}
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks--that must have been it! the href=`#` was actually triggering route change.. removed it as suggested :) thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, when you click on letter and not on button,the link stops the propagation of your mouse click.
Add this class in your css file and apply to `<a>` tag, which holds the letter:

```
.ignore-mouse-event {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

`<a>` tag should be changed to this:

```
<a href="#" class="ignore-mouse-event">{{letter}}</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for this, very clever, may come in handy in future :)